# Stand-alone app to enter records through forms?

Tags: windows, sqlite, desktop-application

I need to find a stand-alone (ie. no OpenOffice-based tools, for instance) Windows application that can present users with forms to enter records into an SQLite database. The goal is to migrate data from Excel sheets into a serverless, single-user database like SQLite.

As a bonus, the application would also have a somewhat-protected admin section so that I can also use it to CRUD data with the same app, but it's not a requirement.

There are a lot of [applications listed on the official SQLite site](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools): Can someone recommend one that is meant for end-users, either open- or closed-source?

Thank you.

---

Edit: the correct term I was looking for is "data entry form". Googling around didn't return a Windows application that makes it possible to easily write data entry forms to let end-users create/edit records, ie. with no direct access to the underlying tables.

Answer (score 1):

I think FileMaker or Microsoft Infopath (May be with Sharepoint Services) could fulfill your needs completely. There are forms in both, validation, different available sources for keeping data, working over net. Both are very flexible and powerful. Infopath with Sharepoint Services can be installed and customized quite quickly.

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather use an SQLite-based solution so that I can easily work with the data outside this end-user application.